# How to use multiple conditions based on 2 columns to create the new column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, conditional-statements

I have 2 dictionaries and i need to create the column based on several condition.

```
dict1 = {'100': BMW, '200': Audi, '300': 'VW'}   
dict2 = {'100': Mercedes, '200': Nissan, '300': 'Renault'}
```

df:

```
class          Code
1              200
1              300
2              300
1              100
2              100
```

I actually want to use dict1 when class is 1 and dict2 when  class is 2

desired output would be like this:

```
  class            Code         Car
    1              200          Audi
    1              300          VW
    2              300          Renault
    1              100          BMW
    2              100          Mercedes
```

I could use .map  if i had no condition but i am not sure what to use now:

```
df['Car'] = df['Code'].map(dict1)
```

Comment: @jezrael can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tested with the follwing code

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'100': 'BMW', '200': 'Audi', '300': 'VW'}
dict2 = {'100': 'Mercedes', '200': 'Nissan', '300': 'Renault'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class':[1,1,2,1],'Code':['200','300','300','100']})
def f(row):
    if row['Class'] == 1:
        val = dict1[row['Code']]
    elif row['Class'] ==2:
        val = dict2[row['Code']]
    else:
        val = dict2[row['Code']]
    return val

df['Car']= df.apply(f,axis=1)

print(df)
```

it prints

```
    Class Code     Car
0      1  200     Audi
1      1  300       VW
2      2  300  Renault
3      1  100      BMW
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just two dictionaries/classes:

```
# note that your dictionary has string key
df['Code'] = df.Code.astype(str)

df['car'] = np.where(df['class']==1,
                     df['Code'].map(dict1),
                     df['Code'].map(dict2) )
```

Output:

```
   class Code       Car
0      1  200      Audi
1      1  300        VW
2      2  300   Renault
3      1  100       BMW
4      2  100  Mercedes
```

Comment: Thanks:) If i have more than 2 dictionaries then what could be the best way to write?

Comment: Any idea for 3 dictionaries?

Comment: How abot `np.select`?

Comment: How i can use 3 dictionaries using `np.select`?